# Do I need to git pull main and not just git fetch in order to rebase another branch off latest main?

Tags: git

I am working on a branch called branchA. `main` has been updated by another and pushed to the remote.

Can I:

```
git co branchA # Make sure to be on branchA
git fetch
git rebase main
```

*without* merging the remote `main` changes into my local `main` branch with `git pull` because rebase goes against the remote copy or do I need to do:

```
git fetch
git checkout main
git pull # to get the changes applied to local main
git checkout branchA
git merge main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `pull` in order to rebase. You could rebase on top of the remote `main` branch you've fetched by referring to it with the `origin/` prefix instead of rebasing on top of your local `main` branch:

```
git checkout branchA # Make sure to be on branchA
git fetch # origin is implied
git rebase origin/main
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first rebase approach should be using the remote tracking branch `origin/main`, *not* the local `main`, as the latter will not be updated by doing a fetch alone:

```
git checkout branchA
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/main
```

The same logic applies to the version which does a merge:

```
git checkout branchA
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main
```

If you want to use the local `main` branch, then you would have to update that specifically, in a separate step:

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
```